# JSON decode php problems

Tags: json

Hello I am rewriting my problem in a more clear way. I have a javascript array just like this:

```
var values=new Array('this is my "name"',encodeURIComponent('me&you&there'),encodeURIComponent('"£$%&/'),'0');
var jsonval=JSON.stringify(values);
$.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url:'dosomething.php',
   data:'action=getdata&myvalues='+jsonval
});
```

I have to use encodeURIComponent cause of posting with ajax.
And at php side i have this:

> $myvals=json_decode($_POST['myvalues'],true);

This fails from decoding the object. an echo of $_POST['myvalues'] something like give this:

```
{"1":"this is my "name"","2":"me&you&there","3":""£$%&/","4":"0"}
```

This seems not to be a valid json object beacause it has """, double quotes insides. Any one know how to avoid this problem?
Thanks

Comment: What's that JSON.stringify you're using? Looks like it's broken.

Comment: this might help - stackoverflow.com/questions/6807180/how-to-escape-a-json-string-to-have-it-in-a-url/

Comment: let say that I have already solved using jquery $.ajax data object notation

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but would escaping your double-quote beside all the special characters with a `\` work?

```
var values=new Array('this is my "name"',encodeURIComponent('me&you&there'),encodeURIComponent('\"£$%&/'),'0');
var jsonval=JSON.stringify(values);
$.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url:'dosomething.php',
   data:'action=getdata&myvalues='+jsonval
});
```

Comment: Ok i can do it but if i have a text like this in the array: asdasd\"asdasd, the escape will produces this:asdasd\\"asdasd, escaping the \ and not the ". So it doesnt work

Comment: In that case could you not escape both characters to produce asdasd\\\"asdasd ?